# Calling A State Property in React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, properties, state, redux

I have a redux store with a state called "Pets" which stores an array of the following:

```
[{"id"2,"name":"Cat"},
 {"id":3,"name":"Dog"},
 {"id":4,"name":"Fish"}
]
```

In my component, I map the states like this: (I'm using redux forms and react-bootstrap-table)

```
class PetsPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state =({
        selected:[]
      });
    this.showRow = this.showRow.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchPets();
  }


render() {
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    previousPage,
    pets
  } = this.props


  if (!pets){
    return (
      <div className="container">
          <div> Loading...</div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (  
      <div className="container">

       <BootstrapTable 
          data={pets} 
          search={true} 
          striped={true}
          hover={true}
          condensed={true}
          selectRow={selectRowProp}>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField="id" isKey={true}>Pet #</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField="name">Company</TableHeaderColumn>
        </BootstrapTable>

          <p> Currently Chosen: <span>  id: {this.state.selected}</span> </p>

          <div className="btn-group">
            <button type="button" onClick={previousPage}  className="btn btn-success btn-lg"><i/> Previous</button>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success btn-lg">Next</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    )
  }
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { pets: state.pets.all };
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'wizard',              
  fields,                      
  destroyOnUnmount: false,    
  validate                    
}, mapStateToProps, actions)(PetsPage)
```

So far, everything WORKS. 
My problem arises when I call the pets prop like this:

```
<p> Currently Chosen: {pets[2].name}</p>
```

I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: pets[2] is undefined
```

Ideally I want to be able to call the name of the pet by the ID which is provided by the "selected" state.

EDIT ---
I noticed the code actually WORKS if I were to go to another page and come back to this page. This is kind of confusing because I thought having the ...loading container would prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you obtain the initial state of `pets`? were those retrieved asynchronously? (which i suspect it is)

When your `BootstrapTable` initially load, the async call was not complete, `pets` was still undefined, hence the error. Then when you go to another page, and come back to this page, your async call was finished, `pets` is now an array, and it works.

If I am right so far, add something like this in your `BootstrapTable`:

```
if(this.props.pets) {
   <p> Currently Chosen: {pets[2].name}</p>
   ... // render your pets props within the 
} else {
   // render some loading indicator
}
```

Edit: if your pets was initialized as an empty array, check the length of the pets instead of the truthy value

Comment: I have an if statement like that in my code:   if (!pets){   

The bootstrap table loads, but just the code after the table, 
<p> Currently Chosen: {pets[2].name}</p> 
does not load. Which is confusing, because if the table loads this should load too?

Comment: I tried the new solution and used <p>currently chosen {this.pets[2].name}. The if statement works but when I put {this.pets[2].name} I get  Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: @lost9123193 what is `this.pets`??

Comment: sorry I mean, this.prop.pets[2].name

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be doing this.props.pets[2] ?
Or this.state.pets[2] ? Unsure exactly what's happening but I don't think pets[2] on it's own would ever be anything. If that doesn't help can you post some more of your code?

Comment: I elaborated on the code, and I used a const {pets} to refer to this.props at the render. I took the pets out of the const and retried this.props.pets[2] and still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just figured it out. 
Following xiaofan2406's suggestion, I literally have to put

```
if(this.props.pets[0])
```

Because

```
if(this.props.pets)
```

will always be true.